# Canvas & Resemble.js: toDataURL() Not Working

Tags: html, canvas, todataurl

I have an html5 video that I am taking screenshots from using:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
```

This draws the screenshot on the canvas just fine. However, what I am trying to do is take multiple screenshots on multiple canvas and compare them with each other using [Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/).

Resemble.js requires two files, and I am trying to use toDataURL() to get these files from the canvases.

```
var image1 = new Image();
        image1.id = "pic"
        image1.src = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
```

And then plugging the images into resemble:

```
resemble(image1).compareTo(image2).onComplete(function(){
            //return data;
            alert(data);
        /*
        {
          misMatchPercentage : 100, // %
          isSameDimensions: true, // or false
          getImageDataUrl: function(){}
        }
        */
            });
```

Where this seems to fail for me is toDataURL(). It does not produce anything from the canvas. What is causing this issue? And am I on the right track with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Give both images time to load:**

```
var loadCount;
var image1,image2;

function compare(){

    // variable to count how many images have fully loaded

    loadCount=0;

    // convert canvas1 to an image
    // call startComparing when done

    image1=new Image();
    image1.onload=startComparing;
    image1.src=canvas1.toDataURL();

    // convert canvas2 to an image
    // call startComparing when done

    image2=new Image();
    image2.onload=startComparing;
    image2.src=canvas2.toDataURL();

}


function startComparing(image1,image2){

    // do the comparison only if we've loaded both images (loadCount==2)

    if(++loadCount==2);

        resemble(image1).compareTo(image2).onComplete(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve part of the issue. However, I am catching a SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tained canvases may not be exported. I'm not sure why the canvas has been 'tainted' since the video file I'm using is saved locally. How can this be solved?

Comment: Yes, local disk storage is deemed by canvas security to be `other domain` and therefore will taint the canvas.  You will need to host both the web page code and your video on the same web server.  If you want to test locally, you will need to install a web server on your local computer (IIS-Express if you're running windows, PHP if you're running something else--or any web server of your choice).